# Is it possible to create custom HTTP errors?

Tags: apache-2.2, http

Well this thing has came to my head now, and can't find any info. I would like to know if it's possible to create custom HTTP errors, no custom pages, like 404 pages, I mean error codes.
The idea came when I saw [Slackware's Connie server](http://connie.slackware.com/) although that may be a simple index page. Well that was my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) describes all possible status and error codes. Everything else is not defined. And if it is not defined in the documentation how should a server and client react when they see such errors?

Comment: Even if it is wrong.  Read the paragraph after the status codes in the RFC.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that page is just returning an error page with a `200 OK` response, so it's nothing exciting.  But there's nothing stopping you from returning a customer error code if you want, although it's not a particularly good idea unless you're only ever going to be returning it to your own custom clients that know what it means and how to deal with it.  I also wouldn't be violating the standard conventions (2xx for success, 4xx for per-request errors, 5xx for server-side problems, etc)

Answer (score 1):

The RFC clearly states the list of codes is extensible.  The Value of the first digit is important.  Unknown status codes are supposed to be treated as X00 where X is the first digit of the status code.